# passwd : Authentication token manipulation error (Different than other questions)

Tags: command-line, bash, password

I'm trying to change password with single command. The command is,

`echo -e "current_password\nnew_password\nnew_password" | passwd`

Here's the Output of the command...

```
Changing password for adarsh.
(current) UNIX password: passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

I don't know why I am getting this error. When I try Interactive mode by just using the command `passwd`, password can be changed successfully without any kind of error...

Any idea how to solve this error?

Comment: I don't think `passwd` accepts standard input (at least not on current versions of Ubuntu; newer versions may do, but require an explicit `--stdin` flag). You may want to look at the `chpasswd` command instead.